# How to edit Web Part properties in REST or CSOM?

Tags: web-part, rest, csom, angularjs

This is a follow-up to my earlier question, [How to get all properties of a Site Page using REST API?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264831/how-to-get-all-properties-of-a-site-page-using-rest-api). Using REST in an AngularJS application, I was able to read the properties of the Web Part Page Title Bar and see if the Image property was populated. Now I realize I have to EDIT the property as well.

Can I use the REST API to edit a web part? Or do I need to use CSOM? I have used CSOM in the past to edit the User Information List (because that's one list you can't edit with REST). But I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting use case, I am not sure if we are able to update via REST API but with CSOM you definitely can update Below

Below is using Powershell CSOM, but same can be used in C# or Javascript object model.

```
function Change-WebPart {
    #variables that needs to be set before starting the script
    $siteURL = "https://spfire.sharepoint.com"
    $userName = "mpadmin@spfire.onmicrosoft.com"
    $webURL = "https://spfire.sharepoint.com"
    $relativePageUrl = "/SitePages/Home.aspx"

    # Let the user fill in their password in the PowerShell window
    $password = Read-Host "Please enter the password for $($userName)" -AsSecureString</pre>
    # set SharePoint Online credentials
    $SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $password)

    # Creating client context object
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webURL)
    $context.credentials = $SPOCredentials

    #get Page file
    $page = $context.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl($relativePageUrl)
    $context.load($page)

    #send the request containing all operations to the server
    try{
        $context.executeQuery()
    }
    catch{
        write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
    }

    #use the WebPartManger to load the webparts on a certain page
    $webPartManager = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
    $context.load($webPartManager.webparts)

    #send the request containing all operations to the server
    try{
        $context.executeQuery()
    }
    catch{
        write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
    }

    #loop through all WebParts to get the correct one and change its property
    foreach($webPartDefinition in $webpartmanager.webparts){
        $context.Load($webPartDefinition.WebPart.Properties)

        #send the request containing all operations to the server
        try{
            $context.executeQuery()
        }
        catch{
            write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
        }

        #Only change the webpart with a certain title
        if ($webPartDefinition.WebPart.Properties.FieldValues.Title -eq "Documents")
        {
            $webPartDefinition.webpart.properties["Title"] = "My Documents"
            $webPartDefinition.SaveWebPartChanges()
        }
    }
}
```

Also sharing some other links for quick referece

https://www.sharepointfire.com/2016/04/editing-web-part-properties-with-powershell-csom-in-sharepoint/

https://sharepointsamurai.wordpress.com/2014/07/27/how-to-use-the-csom-to-update-sharepoint-web-part-properties/

below is using PnPcore
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-web-part-properties/