# SharePoint 2013 REST API Methods to Get File Names from Folders

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, folder

Accessing the SharePoint 2013 API, I have been trying to get files names in each folder in a library and getting errors. I am using Alteryx.

DownloadData Error:

> {"error":{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Value does not fall within the expected range."}}}<

My URLs are below:

[https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/FolderName')/Files](https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/FolderName%27)/Files)

And

[https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('FolderName')/Files](https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(%27FolderName%27)/Files)

1. Might you be able to spot a mistake?
2. In the 2nd one, should I be filling in anything to replace "@target"?
3. Is there a preferred method, assuming one works?

Many thanks as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharePoint REST API endpoint in below format to get the files from specific folder inside document library:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SPConnect/Shared%20Documents/Folder1')/Files
```

You can even get properties associated with files using single API call like:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SPConnect/Shared%20Documents/Folder1')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

**Similar threads**:

1. [How to get all properties of a Site Page using REST API?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264831/how-to-get-all-properties-of-a-site-page-using-rest-api/264832#264832)
2. [List all Files with all Properties/Fileds for a given folder Path](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306566/list-all-files-with-all-properties-fileds-for-a-given-folder-path/306567#306567)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the "Folder URL" which is a server relative path of a folder. Let's say you need the file names from "Folder1" folder of "ABCLibrary" document library.

**URL**: [https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/ABCLibrary/Folder1')/Files](https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/ABCLibrary/Folder1%27)/Files)

In the second one, you are making a cross-domain requests, so you have added SP.AppContextSite(@target) in which you need to pass `?@target='<host web url>'` to the endpoint URI.

**URL:** [https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/ABCLibrary/Folder1')/Files?@target='https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake'](https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(%27/ABCLibrary/Folder1%27)/Files?@target=%27https://team.global.ABCCompany/sites/ABCDataLake%27)

Comment: Thank you Divya!