# List all Files with all Properties/Fields for a given folder Path

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, folder

I'm trying to list all files with all properties/fields (ListItemAllFields) for the given server relative path.

Problems:

1. I'm using this method to list files:

```
 https://<sub-domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/<site-name>/Shared Documents/folder path')/Files
```

This method list files in for given folder. I want to list all files for the given folder and all sub-folder in it.
Is it possible with a single API call?

2. If we want to list all fields for a given file, we use `ListItemAllFields`:

```
https://<subdomain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/<site-name>/Shared Documents/file path')/ListItemAllFields
```

Can't we combine this with the first method I mentioned above? I don't want to make API calls for each and every file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use REST API endpoint in this format:

```
_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/<site-name>/Shared Documents/folder path')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Similar thread: [How to get all properties of a Site Page using REST API?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264831/how-to-get-all-properties-of-a-site-page-using-rest-api/264832#264832)

---

Try using REST endpoint in below format to get all files & folders inside specific folder:

```
https://server/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<folder url>)?$expand=Folders,Files
```

More information at:

1. [Get all Files and Folders in one call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call)
2. [Get all SharePoint Document Library Files and Folders at a ServerRelativeUrl in One REST Call](https://sympmarc.com/2016/04/23/get-all-sharepoint-document-library-files-and-folders-at-a-serverrelativeurl-in-one-rest-call/)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your response. 
I also want to list all files in folders and subfolders.
`Shared Documents/folder1/folder2/folder3`. If I give the folder path as a `Shared Documents/folder1`, I also want files inside folder2 and folder3.

Comment: Check links in updated answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey! Thanks For your help. I have looked into the document. In my case, folder depth can be different. But no worries. I will implement a recursive approach.

Again, Thanks for your help. Appreciated.